# Handling different links differently in QTextBrowser

Tags: qt, hyperlink, pyqt, qtextbrowser

I'm trying to set up a QTextBrowser where most hyperlinks work normally, but hyperlinks that begin with an arbitrary prefix will instead call a function.

@three-pineapples supplied some great instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19454113/pyside-pyqt-is-it-possible-to-make-strings-that-you-attach-to-the-qtextbrowser/19475367#19475367) for how to achieve the latter behavior, detecting a prefix on a url and calling a method based on that url.

The problem is, in order for this to work, the QTextBrowser's `setOpenLinks()` method has to be set `False` so that the QTextBrowser will emit the `anchorClicked()` signal. Otherwise, the prefixed links are handled automatically by Qt and have no custom behavior. But if I set `setOpenLinks() False`, normal links now don't work properly.

Any ideas how to re-implement link-handling manually in the environment with `setOpenLinks()` set `False`, or else getting the custom behavior on the prefixed links in the environment where it is set `True`? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Method 1: full control (but duplicating Qt code)**

If you want to have full control, disables Qt's link handling mechanism using `setOpenLinks(false)` and implement link handling yourself completely, based on the Qt implementation ([`QTextBrowserPrivate::_q_activateAnchor`](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/widgets/widgets/qtextbrowser.cpp?h=5.9#n205)) for normal links:

> ```
> bool isFileScheme =
>         url.scheme() == QLatin1String("file")
> #if defined(Q_OS_ANDROID)
>         || url.scheme() == QLatin1String("assets")
> #endif
>         || url.scheme() == QLatin1String("qrc");
> if ((openExternalLinks && !isFileScheme && !url.isRelative())
>     || (url.isRelative() && !currentURL.isRelative() && !isFileScheme)) {
>     QDesktopServices::openUrl(url);
>     return;
> }
>
> q->setSource(url);
> ```

So, open the url using [`QTextBrowser::setSource`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextbrowser.html#source-prop) or open it externally using [`QDesktopServices::openUrl`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdesktopservices.html#openUrl).

**Method 2: integrated approach**

Enable Qt's link handling mechanism using `setOpenLinks(true)`. `anchorClicked` will be emitted in general when the link has a file scheme or more exactly when the following condition fails:

> ```
> if ((openExternalLinks && !isFileScheme && !url.isRelative())
>     || (url.isRelative() && !currentURL.isRelative() && !isFileScheme))
> ```

If you do not call [`setSource`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextbrowser.html#source-prop) or change the content of the [`QTextDocument`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html#document-prop), the source will be automatically set to the clicked url.